# C++: ScopeGuard vs return check and exception handling?

Tags: c++, error-handling

Consider these code happen in real life.

A library code has a function called log_on(), it returns false on fail, true on success, but it has too many false cases.

Before return true/false, it needs to call a callback function application specified. So it looks like:

```
bool log_on() {
    // do something else
    bool success = false;
    scope_guard guard = [&success]() {
        if (success) {
            callback(success);
        } else {
            callback(false);
        }
    }
    success = prepare_logon();
    if (success) {
         int rc = send_password();
         if (rc == PASSWORD_ERR) {
             return false;
         }
    }
    if (!send_some_data()) return false;
    success = true;
    return true;
}
```

The purpose is too many return cases, and need to call some callbacks if true and false is returned. So someone use scopeguard to do this. Is this a good practice to replace return check with scopeguard use? And in this case, the library code is required not to throw, if user specify a function callback that will throw, so error handling is a problem?

Comment: On `rc == PASSWORD_ERR` path, this code will call `callback(true)` and then return `false`.

Comment: Same problem on `!send_some_data()` path (also, did you mean to call `send_some_data()` even if `prepare_logon()` failed?) That's kind of the point - it's too easy to mess up.

Comment: no, please notice that success = false, set by default at init. no need to set success = false elsewhere

Comment: However, there's `success = prepare_logon()` afterwards. That might set `success` to `true`, but there are a couple of paths that return `false` later, without resetting `success`.

Comment: correct, this is for demo only

Comment: Well, it does successfully demonstrate how fragile this approach is.

Comment: well, if someone reuse the success flag without noticing this, then it's his fault.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to do this, I'd move the real work into a helper function:

```
bool log_on_impl() { /* real work here*/ }

bool log_on() {
  bool success = log_on_impl();
  callback(success);
  return success;
}
```

This way, `log_on_impl` could do early returns to its heart's content; the callback will still be called with the correct value.

Comment: so, if code doesnt use exception at all, does it imply no need scopeguard? as you illustrated return code check is done outside.